# How to specify data type in Soapui request

Tags: soapui

I have the following section in my SOAPUI request that I'm trying to pass to a web service for testing:

```
<DataList>
    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
    <Element/>
</DataList>
```

The list of elements can be of 2 different types specified in the WSDL definition, my question is how do I specify the data type of DataList?

Here is the sequence defined:

```
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DataList" nillable="true" type="ns:tDataValues"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Here is the sequence type defined:

```
<xsd:complexType name="tDataValues">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Element" nillable="true" type="ns:Data_Value"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Here are the 2 types defined:

```
<xsd:complexType name="DataValue1">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="ns:Data_Value">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="FieldValue1" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="DataValue2">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="ns:Data_Value">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="FieldValue2" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to address this for our app by doing the following in the soap request.  In our case, the 'value' element has more than one type:

```
<value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">foo</value>
```

This may require the server code to be able to handle this.  In our case, our app is a JEE 5 app using JAXB/JAXWS to handle the web service calls.